Как правильно импортировать в Nodejs файл .ENV
Народ, подскажите,  как правильно импортировать на сервере nodejs файл .env.
На версиях nodejs старше 20ой встроена поддержка файлов .env без сторонних модулей.
в варианте с require -- require('dotenv').config()
все прекрасно работает!
но вот с модулями при импортировании не могу понять как импортировать
Мой вариант
import dotenv from 'env';
dotenv.config();

выдает ошибку

node server.js
node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:845   throw new
ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND(packageName, fileURLToPath(base), null);
^
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'env' imported from
G:\projects\modules_tamplate\server.js
at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:845:9)
at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:918:18)
at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1148:11)
at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:390:12)
at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:359:25)
at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:234:38)
at ModuleWrap. (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:87:39)
at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:86:36) {   code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
Node.js v21.7.1

Подскажите как правильно импортировать файл .env?
server.js &&  .env в корне папки на одном уровне

import dotenv from 'dotenv';. или https://nodejs.org/en/learn/command-line/how-to-read-environment-variables-from-nodejs

Прошу Коллег исправить меня, если я не прав, но я понял так.
Не надо ничего импортировать.
Чтобы файл .env  был прочитан и распознан, надо при запуске указать его в
scripts в package.json
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --env-file .env server.js "
  }

Надо отметить тот факт, что если кто-то захочет использовать данный вариант, для webpack,
"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --env-file .env"
  }

то это работать не будет...
